# TYPO3 11.5 changed slug ends in wrong redirect

Tags: typo3, slug

TYPO3 11.5.26.

I have had two pages called "test" in the page tree:

1. page type=folder id=34 slug=test
2. page type=standard id=10 slug=test1

Then I did rename the slug for **1** into 'test-folder' and the slug for **2** into 'test'.

1. page type=folder id=34 slug=test-folder
2. page type=standard id=10 slug=test

The page properties for 2 show well https//my-typo3-site.com/test in the slug field. But when I enter https//my-typo3-site.com/test into the browser tab url then it is immediately redirected into https//my-typo3-site.com/test-folder/ and I get a 404 page not found error. But the test-folder is a folder page and is not meant to be used for the front end.

How can I clear the slug cache in order also the TYPO3 frontend will show me the slugs as they are already in the backend?
Or how does it come that the subpage test is redirected into test-folder?

Comment: For folders you can enter any slug like heidewitzka or just leave it empty.
Without special setup they are not used at all and just tend to disturb like in your case.

Comment: Yes, of course the slug field can be any name. But it does not help me. I renamed the folder slug into 'unused'. Then the page for test gets redirected to 'unused' .

Comment: When I save the changes, then a popup window shows this:
---------------------------------------------
Slugs updated and redirects created
Because you renamed a slug, the slugs of all sub-pages were updated and redirects were created for you automatically.

Revert update
Revert redirects only

Comment: seems you've the redirects extension running.
You can enter it in the backend module and delete some or all redirects there,

Comment: I usually like to disable / uninstall the redirects extension completely,, so those things can't happen.

Comment: Indeed, you have seen this right. I have never noticed this redirect extension and its backend module.

my-typo3-site.com  /test /unused/ (Page ID: 34, Status Code: 307) 
my-typo3-site.com  /test-1 /test/ (Page ID: 10, Status Code: 307) 
my-typo3-site.com  /test-folder /unused/ (Page ID: 34, Status Code: 307)

Comment: You can write this as solution. Then I will give you my vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you've the redirects extension running. You can enter it in the backend module and delete some or all redirects there.
I usually like to disable / uninstall the redirects extension completely, so those things can't happen.

Strange things with slugs respectively URLs can happen when the extension "redirects" is installed. Your case is a simple one, but finding the reason for redirecting can be quite cumbersome if a slug is changed several times.

Using the extension "redirects" can be quite useful for SEO and usability aspects but the editor has to be aware of it and know how to use it.